# pyTelegramBot decorator is not detecting update

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I'm trying to build a simple Telegram Bot that echos me a hello whenever I ping it. My Code looks as follows:

```
print("Loading...")

key = "<TOKEN>"

bot = telebot.TeleBot(key)
bot.send_message(text = "HI o/", chat_id = "<My Chat ID>")
print("Done.")

bot.polling()

@bot.message_handler(commands = ["hello"])
def send_hello(message):
    #print(message)
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hi There!")
```

The initial message in the setup goes through, but when I type /hello in the chat the bot does not react. What am I missing here? This follows exactly the example in the documentation. What am I doing incorrectly. Also: Is there a way to make the bot react to every message not covered by any other function?

Comment: hi this is normally due to incorrect chat_id, are u getting the chat_id from this https://api.telegram.org/bot_token/getUpdates?

Comment: Yes, the message ID is correct. It was originally taken from the getUpdates function and I've written my own handler, which downloaded these for me. As I said, the first message I print manually goes through.

The api pyTelegramBot actually extracts the ID from each message. Here's the docs: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI